# Norm Spencer: voice of Cyclops has passed away

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Norm Spencer, Voice of Cyclops in X-Men: The Animated Series, Has Died](https://comicbook.com/tv-shows/news/norm-spencer-dead-cyclops-x-men-animated-series-actor/):

> The X-Men community around the globe suffered a sad loss this week, as news broke that actor Norm Spencer had passed away. Spencer provided the voice for Scott Summers, aka Cyclops, in the beloved show X-Men: The Animated Series. He voiced the character, which remains one of the most popular X-Men in the franchise, in 68 episodes of the series, from 1992 to 1997.